# MySql table data is deleted automatically from online server

Tags: mysql

My MySql table data is deleted automatically in online server. What are the possible causes? Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL injection is a possible cause

Comment: can you explain  more

Comment: I have developed a website and its is currently running online, and the table are already filled with data by the user. Time and again few table rows are completely deleted first I thought someone had the password and deleted them and kept the database log for that purpose but also then the data are being deleted continuously and there is no any delete query. Please help I am in a great problem.

Comment: One possible cause is your server is bewitched. But if you give us more information, that could help identify the problem instead of trying random guesses.

Comment: ok what are the information should I provide?